# Are questions in regards to air ride allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions in regards to air ride fabrication allowed?  Such as, what degree of tolerance should you allow at full ride height when using an air ride suspension?  After searching through the tags I didn't see this tag created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The help center states](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories.

In short, yes it's on topic

Comment: I absolutely concur! Yes, this is definitely on topic for the site, so please @Darth_Vader, ask away!